# How to disapper the submenu div element on mouse out

Tags: jquery, mouseout

Hi I have a menu and submenu there is a div element for the submenu.I m able to get the div element when i hover on the hyperlink of my first menu li,but it doesn't disappear when i take out my mouse from the div element.It continously appears,so i want to hide the div element when i mouseout the div or somewhere else.On mouseout im not written the code for "display","none" due to this on hover the link it works but it remains appears.

**Html**

```
<ul class="main-nav">
<li ><a href="#" id="menu1">Products & Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="menu1">Solution and Technologies</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="menu1">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="menu1">Investors</a></li>
<li style="border:none;"><a href="#" id="menu1">Newsroom</a></li>
</ul>
<!--1st drop down menu -->
<div id="dropmenu1"  class="dropmenudiv" style=" position:absolute; font-size:12px; z-index:1;  display:none;  border:1px solid #D8D8D8;">
<a id="consumer1" style="visibility:hidden;"  href="#">Consumer & Home</a>
<a href="#">Aerospace & Defense</a>
<a href="#">Safety & Security</a>
<a href="#">Scanning & Mobile Productivity</a>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
  .dropmenudiv a{ background:url(images/dropdown_bg.jpg); text-decoration:none; display:block; line-height:14px; padding:2px;}
    ul.main-nav{list-style:none; border:1px solid #666; overflow:hidden; background:url(images/mnu_grad_normal.jpg) repeat-x; height:37px; line-height:36px;}
    ul.main-nav li { float:left; font-size:12px; border-right:1px solid #999; padding:0px 32px;}
    ul.main-nav li a{ color:#000000; text-decoration:none;}
    ul.main-nav li a:hover{ color:#FF0000;}
```

**JS:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#menu1').mouseover(function(){
        $('#dropmenu1').css("display","block");
        $('#dropmenu1').css({'width':'202px','height':'auto'});
      $('#menu1').mouseout(function(){
        });
```

Comment: Your mouseout function is empty

Comment: actually i already use "display":"none" in mouseout function but it doesnt work as it is i mentioned.

Comment: In jQuery there is also a hover() method that I find more readable than mouseover/mouseout.

Comment: @user1673379 please update your code to the current version with the implemented mousout

Comment: @user1673379 did you even read your code and the jQuery docs before posting here ?

Comment: doen't it seam like mouseout lies inside of mouseover?

Comment: actually simply i say im beginner and learning the jquery.

Comment: yes it is.ohh that is a big mistake actually at the time of posting it happens.Sir can you please clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 2):

Do it without javascript. Css only menu [Css Dropdown menu](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/)
and a link to the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JRpju/)

```
<ul id="nav">
<li ><a href="#">Products & Services</a>
  <ul>
      <li><a id="consumer1" href="#">Consumer & Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Aerospace & Defense</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Safety & Security</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Scanning & Mobile Productivity</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Solution and Technologies</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Investors</a></li>
<li style="border:none;"><a href="#">Newsroom</a></li>

</ul>
#nav{
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:10px;
       float:left;
    width:100%;
   }
#nav li{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
}
#nav a{
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#nav ul{
    background:#fff;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0);
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
}
#nav ul li{
    padding-top:1px;
    float:none;
}
#nav ul a{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#nav li:hover ul{ 
    left:0; 
}
#nav li:hover a{ 
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#nav li:hover ul a{ 
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover{ 
    background:#333;
}
```

Comment: +1, but you should fix that CSS, your menu is displaced. Normalize margins and paddings, and fix z-indexes, so the lists are not hidden below links. Here is another alternative with [display:none/block](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/suRE6/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Bind with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','#divid',function(){
  // ...
})

$(document).on('mouseleave','#divid',function(){
  // ...
})
```

---

Consider using [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

> The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during the time the mouse is within the element.

Usage:

```
$(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)
```

---

Pseudo solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/7PH6d/1/

---

**Further reading:**

[The friggin' API](http://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the .mouseover. Your mouseout-function is in the mouseover function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#menu1').mouseover(function(){
        $('#dropmenu1').css("display","block");
        $('#dropmenu1').css({'width':'202px','height':'auto'});
      }); //<----Close the mouseover
      $('#menu1').mouseout(function(){
        $("#dropmenu1").css("display","none"); //Should work
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

At first make your identifiers unique, then you can setTimeout to pause disappearing of the target div immediately after your mouse departs from the main menu link. The script can look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var target_div = null; // div#dropmenu1 etc.
    var timer = false; // for delayed hide
    $('.main-nav a').mouseenter(function () {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = false;
        }
        $('.dropmenudiv').css('display', 'none'); //hide all divs
        target_div = $('#drop' + this.id); // #dropmenu1 etc.
        target_div.css({
            "display": "block", //show
            'width': '202px',
                'height': 'auto'
        });
    }).mouseleave(leaving);

    $('.dropmenudiv').mouseenter(function () {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = false;
        }
        target_div = $(this);
    }).mouseleave(leaving);

    function leaving() {
        target_div = null;
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            var divs = $('.dropmenudiv');
            if (target_div) {
                divs = divs.not(target_div);
            }
            divs.css('display', 'none');
            timer = false;
        }, 2000); //hide after two seconds
    }
});
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7PH6d/4/

Answer (score 0):

You have used the same ID for multiple elements in a page which is not the correct procedure.

I made certain changes and it's working, it may answer this question but i would you recommend you to read tutorials on creating menus because this looks little messy.

Here is the Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Te3dW/

Javascript function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li:nth-child(1),#dropmenu1').hover(function(){
    $('#dropmenu1').css("display","block");
    $('#dropmenu1').css({'width':'202px','height':'auto'});
    },function(){
        $('#dropmenu1').css("display","none");
    });
});
```

Happy Coding